# Unable to access inherited variable

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

In the following example, why am I unable to assign to the inherited variable `a` in my derived class `bar`?

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
protected:
    int a;
};

class bar : public foo
{
public:
    bar(int _a) : a{_a} {}
    int GetA() const { return a; }
};

int main() {
    bar b{5};
    std::cout << b.GetA() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I receive the [following compiler error](http://ideone.com/dp8irJ):

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'bar::bar(int)':
prog.cpp:12:16: error: class 'bar' does not have any field named 'a'
  bar(int _a) : a{_a} {}
                ^
```

Doesn't my `bar` class now have a variable `bar::a`? Or does it only have access to `foo:a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `foo::a` from the derived class `bar`, but not initialise it in the constructor's initialiser list. That can only initialise the base class directly. Thus, you should instead

```
class foo
{
protected:
    foo(int _a) : a(_a) {}        // initialise member
    int a;
};

class bar : public foo
{
    int b;
public:
    bar(int _a) : foo{_a}, b(0) {}  // initialise base, then member
    int GetA() const { return a; }  // fine: access protected member of base
};
```

Comment: Oh okay I see the issue. Thanks. So it looks like calling a delegating constructor to the base class is the solution?

Comment: This is not a *delegating* constructor, but otherwise your observation is correct: a derived class must initialise all its bases. If the base's constructor is not explicitly called in the derived's constructor, then an implicit call (to the default constructor) will be generated (and an error occur if the base has no default constructor).

Comment: in the line `bar(int _a) : foo{_a}, b(0) {}` the comment could be misleading; initializations are always done in the same order regardless of the order listed in the initializer list. (The order is base classes first, in order that they appear in the class definition, and then member variables in the order they appear in the class definition).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is correct.  The class `bar` doesn't have any data members.  It's parent does.

A traditional method is to use the Parent class' constructor:

```
class foo
{
  protected:
    foo(int value) : a(value)
    { ; }
    int a;
};

class bar : public foo
{
  public:
    bar(int value)
      : foo(value)
    { ; }
};
```

Another method is to access the `foo` variable in the constructor:

```
  bar(int value)
  {
    foo::a = value; // parent scope added for emphasis.
  }
```

Comment: what's that empty statement doing inside your constructors?

Comment: It's a style issue.  I saw a person's code and he said he does it to emphasize and empty block.